# Howto install log4cxx with conan?

Tags: log4cxx, conan

I am starting to experiment with conan. I found this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/vthiery/conan-log4cxx) but I am not sure what to do with it.

I would like to install log4cxx via `conan install`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That github repository belongs to an pre conan 1.0 recipe. There are some repositories for packages and binaries you can directly install with `conan install`:

- Conan-center: https://bintray.com/conan/conan-center
- Bincrafters: https://bintray.com/bincrafters/public-conan

None of them have right now `log4cxx`. If you need that dependency, the best would be trying to update it to conan 1.0, collaborating with the original author, or with the bincrafters community in https://github.com/bincrafters.

The process to try if the recipe works is:

- git clone  & cd repo
- conan create . user/channel

That will fire the local creation of the package. In the case of that log4cxx repo, it is failing in my case, because of the `self.run("sudo apt-get install --yes libapr1-dev libapr1 libaprutil1-dev libaprutil1")`, as I am running in Windows. The recipe seems to be prepared only for Linux/Apt. There are now a dedicated recipe method `system_requirements()` that should contain the installation of system level packages, instead of the `build()` method.